# Could not load file or assembly '' or one of its project dependencies for user control in solution

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit

I have my solution structure as below with references denoted by ->:

```
Common (x64)
->Library

Business (x64)
->Common
->Library

GUIMain (x64)
->Common
->Business
->Library

Dialogs (x64)
-> Common
-> Business
-> Library
```

Now i have created a new project to create user control that will be used in Dialogs and UI both.

```
UserControls  (Any CPU)
  -> Common
  -> Business
  -> Library
```

Common contains few constants and data object classes to populate data in a grid.

When ever i drop that user control on a form which is created in Dialogs project shows me dependency load issue for business and common.

See below image for reference:
[image]

What am i missing related to this reference issue??

Comment: Hi, is this user control WPF or winforms?

Comment: It's winforms and sorry i was forgot to add that tag..

Comment: Make sure you did not add the control to the toolbox with "Choose Items".  That can never work when you use a version number like 1.5.0.18438.  The copy of the control will get instantly stale when you rebuild.  The toolbox must auto-populate.  Bad versioning strategy btw.

Comment: @HansPassant: I did not add the control to the toolbar. I have just build my solution and then adding to form from the toolbar. User Controls referencing existing projects which are already in my Solution and all have same version number. Yesterday it start working to add it from the toolbar but today it showing this error.